# Is it possible to active Android Beam "Tab to beam"-screen with a simulated touchevent?

Tags: android, events, touch, nfc, android-beam

On ICS when you want to beam some NdefMessage you have to touch the screen ("touch to beam"). I would like to know if it is possible to beam data only with some code, without any user touch. 
Is it possible to beam some data by simulating a touch?

Comment: I guess you are aware that you can talk to tags without 'the beam'.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it is not. Most likely this is kind of a security issue. If you force the User to touch the screen, he is aware, that at least some data is leaving his phone. This way, no-one can sniff the data, you are attempting to send. 
The NFC feature on phones is not like a RFID-card, where one is able to write data permanently on the chip. I think NFC on android is more like an interface to NFC. You are able to "pipe" data through it, but storing is not yet possible. In the moment the User "beams" data, internal code is triggered to send the data you prepared.

There may be a way to send it via code, if you root your phone, look at the internals, change them, and build your custom-rom.